# cocos 2d is not full screen in iphone & ios6

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a problem where

in ios 5 & 5.1 on the ipad the scene appears fine

but in ios 6 on the ipad & iphone 5.0 & 5.1 it appears with black edges

.. and completely black on the iphone ios6.

how do I fix this to work on the iphone & ios 6 for ipad & iphone?

here's the code I'm working with:

https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/smooth-drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the screen size from the director and replace it with the hard coded resolution for the ipad. This was you can also get it to support retina

Answer (score 1):

You need a Default-568h@2x.png image in your resources for iOS to provision the full 4 inch screen when launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning stating "Retina 4 display, Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image". Click on this warning, and a message will appear stating "Would you like Xcode to add this image for you?". Click on Add and run the program.

Comment: yea that just didnt fix the issue